# Getting value of a control on Datarepeater

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to get value of a text box, say at row 4 of a datarepeater.
I did it by moving control to it, but that does not work the way I want.
I used code DataRepeater1.currentIndex=5, and then picked the value.  Is there any possibility of getting the value without moving control to this row.  I mean the way we get value from datagridview (vrName=datagridview1.item(1,1).value)

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the DataRepeater's [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b63ha24w%28VS.80%29.aspx) and navigate with MoveNext, MoveLast, MovePrevious and MoveFirst through it. There you can find your value without moving control to this row.

```
    For i As Int32 = 0 To Me.AddressTableAdapterBindingSource.Count - 1
        'you don't need to iterate through all rows if you have the index, this is only an example'
        Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(Me.AddressTableAdapterBindingSource(i), DataRowView).Row
        Dim ID As Int32 = DirectCast(row("AddressID"), Int32)
        Dim City As String = DirectCast(row("City"), String)
        'you could also change the value'
        row("City") = "[" & ID & "] " & City
    Next
```

Comment: Do While DsGetIDsForCurrentPpr.tblPaperEnrSummary.Rows.Count > vrUPD
            bsGetIDsForCurrentPpr.MoveNext()
            Dim vrLogStatusUPD As String = DsGetIDsForCurrentPpr.tblPaperEnrSummary.Rows(vrUPD).Item("LogStatus")
            If vrLogStatusUPD = "Suspended" Then
                drCPanel.CurrentItem.Controls("cmdSuspendpaper").Text = "Restore"
            End If loop

Comment: System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message="Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'."

Comment: Also, can I assign value like

Comment: DirectCast(DirectCast(bsGetIDsForCurrentPpr(0), DataRow)("LogStatusLabel1"), String) = Text

Comment: You dont need to post a comment for every sentence. You should debug and set a breakpoint where you get your invalid cast exception. You can see what type it really is by hold on the mouse over the variable or by a QuickWatch.
It might be a DataRowView instead.
But by the way, is it correct that i was assuming that you mean the DataRepeater of the the Winforms-`Visual Basic Power Packs`?

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Yes we mean DataRepeater of the the Winforms-Visual Basic Power Packs.  I tried your code with changing it like this  Dim ID As Int32 = DirectCast(row("LogStatus"), Int32)  It returns error LogStatus is not part of tblABC.

Comment: I mean to get value from Datarepeater, not from my table.  Also, I need to update valued in datarepeater lables.  Thanks